# BlueStacks 4 shows error and does not start in windows 10

Tags: bluestacks

When I start BlueStacks 4 shows error and does not start in Windows 10.

Error:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a  correct format.

Comment: Please reinstall it and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but here's the answer (If ur on windows):

• Search regedit in the Windows-Search and click on the registry editor.
• Go into Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWAR\BlueStacks
• Now, using STRG+F, search for the Registry-Error (Somewhere in the Error there
should be something like: "at Registration.get_YourError", in which case YourError is the
Registry-Error. In my case it was TranslucentControlsTransparency) 
• Now just delete the file and...
Congrats! It's fixed!